# c++ Print function print class objects values directory instead of value

Tags: c++, class

I'm working with c++ classes and I got to deal with some data. I had to use 2 classes with composition relation. I had a problem at printing. The function  prints the directory of the value, instead of the value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class Examen;
class Comisie{
private:
    char *descriere;
    int numarMembri;
    char **numeMembri;
public:
    Comisie(char *, int);
    ~Comisie(){}
    friend void addMembru(char *);
    friend void afisare(Examen **, int);
};

Comisie::Comisie(char *numeExamen, int nrMembri){
    this->descriere =new char[strlen(numeExamen)];
    strcpy(this->descriere, numeExamen);
    this->numarMembri = nrMembri;
    this->numeMembri =new char*[nrMembri];
    char nume[50];
    for(int i = 0; i<nrMembri; i++){
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.get(nume, 50);
        this->numeMembri[i] = new char[strlen(nume)];
        strcpy(this->numeMembri[i], nume);
    }
}

class Examen{
private:
    int oraInceput;
    char *numeExamen;
    Comisie *comisie;
public:
    Examen(int, int, char *);
    Examen(Examen &);
    ~Examen(){}
    friend void afisare(Examen **, int);
    friend Comisie;
};

Examen::Examen(int oraInceput, int nrMembri, char *numeExamen){
    this->oraInceput = oraInceput;
    this->numeExamen = new char[strlen(numeExamen)];
    strcpy(this->numeExamen, numeExamen);
    Comisie temp2(numeExamen, nrMembri);
    this->comisie = &temp2;
}

int powInt(int x, int y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        x *= 10;
    }
    return x;
}

int parseInt(char* chars)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int len = strlen(chars);
    for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
    {
        int n = chars[len - (x + 1)] - '0';
        sum = sum + powInt(n, x);
    }
    return sum;

}

int char_ora_to_min(char ora[]){
    int i = 0;
    while(ora[i] != ':') i++;
    char c_ora[2];
    char c_min[5];
    strncpy(c_ora, ora, i);
    strcpy(c_min, ora+i+1);
    int i_ora, i_minut;
    i_ora = parseInt(c_ora);
    i_minut = parseInt(c_min);
    i_minut += i_ora*60;

    return i_minut;
}

Examen ** citire(int nrExamene){
    Examen **lista = (Examen**)malloc(sizeof(Examen)*nrExamene);
    for(int i = 0; i<nrExamene; i++){
        char c_ora[10];
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.get(c_ora, 10);
        int ora;
        ora = char_ora_to_min(c_ora);
        char numeEx[100];
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.get(numeEx, 100);
        int nrM;
        std::cin>>nrM;
        Examen temp(ora, nrM, numeEx);
        lista[i] = &temp;
    }

    return lista;
}

//print function

void afisare(Examen **lista, int nrExamene){
    for(int i = 0; i<nrExamene; i++){
        std::cout<<lista[i]->numeExamen<<std::endl<<"Ora inceperii: "<<lista[i]->oraInceput<<":"<<lista[i]->oraInceput<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Participanti:"<<std::endl;

        for(int j = 0; j < lista[i]->comisie->numarMembri; j++){
            std::cout<<"- "<<lista[i]->comisie->numeMembri[j]<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}



//int numarare(Examen**, int nrExamene, char *numeMembru){ return 0;}

int main(){
    int nrExamene;
    std::cin>>nrExamene;
    Examen **lista_examene = citire(nrExamene);
    afisare(lista_examene, nrExamene);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPRz9.png)

The input is:

```
1
8:00
Comisia a
1
Ana
```

The output should be:

```
Comisia a
Ora inceperii: xx:xx
Participanti:
- Ana
```

So the function (void afisare) can `acces lista[i]->numeExamen`, but can't acces `lista[i]->comisie->numeMembri[j]` and `lista[i]->comisie->numarMembri`

Comment: A few notes: 1) Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast in C++, then take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong; 2) In this case you use `malloc` which you should not do, especially since you allocate wrong size for your memory; 3) Don't save pointer to local variables. The life-time of local variables ends when thee block they were defined in ends. That means you will have an array of invalid pointer; 4) To solve all these problems, (and probably the one you want to ask about) use a `std::vector` of `Examen` objects: `std::vector<Examen>`.

Comment: `char **numeMembri;` Change that to `std::vector<std::string>`.  Then change this: `char *descriere;` to this: `std::string descriere;`.  That gets you started in untangling the mess that `Comisie` is in now.  Then you should make similar changes to `Examen`

Comment: Once the code consists of [idiomatic C++](https://ideone.com/QzaOoV) using `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc. the output shows up.